# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all() using & and an if statement

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find whenever 2 columns contain the number 2 at the same time, and add it to a count.

I tried following the recommendations of this post [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)  in my code:

```
count = 0
if (df['Bedroom2'] == 2).bool() & (df['Car'] == 2).bool():
count += 1

print(count)
```

However, it still displays the error:
`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count the number of the rows where two columns contain specific numbers, you can use

```py
count = ((df['Bedroom2'] == 2) & (df['Car'] == 2)).sum()
```

Your problem is that you use [`Series.bool()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.bool.html) on a Series which contains more than 1 element

```
>>> pd.Series([True]).bool()
True

>>> pd.Series([True, False]).bool()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1577, in bool
    self.__nonzero__()
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1527, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it according to the [post you have linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 2], 'col2': [4, 2, 3, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

count = len(df[(df['col1']==2) & (df['col2']==2)])
print(count) #outputs 2
```

Basically you make a dataframe that meets your conditions and count the length of it.